# Summarize dataframe: key column (unique values) plus flag if all rows for the key have the same 'type'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have something like this:

```
data = {'SKU':[1,1,2,1,2,2,3],
        'QTY':[5,12,2,24,1,2,12],
        'TYPE': ['M','C','M','C','M','M','C']
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

OUTPUT:

   SKU  QTY TYPE
0    1    5    M
1    1   12    C
2    2    2    M
3    1   24    C
4    2    1    M
5    2    2    M
6    3   12    C
```

And I want a list of unique SKUs and a true / false column indicating if Type = C for all instances of that SKU.

Something like this:

```
  SKU  Case
0   1 False
1   2 False
2   3  True
```

I've tried all manner of combinations of groupby, filter, agg, value_counts, etc. and just can't seem to find a reasonable way to achieve this.

Any help would be much appreciated. I'm sure the answer will be humbling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(df.groupby('SKU')['TYPE'].agg(lambda x: np.all(x == 'C')).reset_index())
```

Prints:

```
   SKU   TYPE
0    1  False
1    2  False
2    3   True
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us do `groupby` + `nunique`

```
s=df.TYPE.eq('C').groupby(df['SKU']).all().reset_index()


   SKU   TYPE
0    1  False
1    2  False
2    3   True
```

Comment: SKU 2 should be false - all values of Type for sku 2 are equal, but they are 'M'. I think @andrej has got it.

Comment: That does the trick, but I went with the prior response because the groupby()[].agg approach is something I tried, just couldn't get right.